# Как наследовать от Array в ES6 с использованием Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel, extend

После вызова `super()`, `this` начинает ссылаться на то,
что вернул родительский конструктор. `Array` возвращает массив.
а у массива в цепочке прототипов нет ни какого `Range.prototype`
по этому метод `say` работать не будет.

```js
class Range extend Array {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.range = true
  }

  say(){ 
    alert(`im range ${this.range}`) 
  }

}

let range = new Range()
range.say() // Error: range.say is not a function
```

Как же нам наследовать от `Array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Babel нет поддержки расширения встроенных классов таких как `Array`.
Дело в том что если конструктор `super()` что-то возвращает, то `this` начинает ссылаться на это возвращенное значение, можно было бы в коде конструктора `Range` написать что-то вроде

```js
class Range extends Array {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.__proto__ = Range.prototype // fix
    this.isRange = true
  }

}
```

Но тогда мы бы не могли нормально наследовать от `Range`, так как приходилось бы повторять ту же операцию с восстановлением прототипа.

Правильное решение такое, мы просто создадим обертку на массив и наследуемся от неё:

```js
function ArrayWrapper() { }
ArrayWrapper.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)


class Range extends ArrayWrapper {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.isRange = true
  }

  say(){ alert('im range!') }

}

let range = new Range()
rande instanceof Range // true
rande instanceof Array // true

range.say() // im range
range.isRange // true
range.forEach(item => {}) // work
```

Правда, если вы наследуете от массива, вам стоит не забыть перекрыть все родительские методы типа `slice`, чтобы они возвращали не массивы, а копии `Range`.

=)

Comment: Этот вариант (даже если мы честно стащим с массива все его методы) фейлится на таком тесте: `var a = new Range(); a[3] = 0; console.log(a.length);` Должно быть 4, а будет 0.

Comment: Нет, не должно быть 4, так как наследоавние не наследует данный функционал, а наследует только лишь методы.

Comment: Если мы хотим настоящее наследование, как оно есть в ES6, то должно. Вот, попробуй в любом браузере, поддерживающем ES6: `class A extends Array {}; var a = new A; a[3] = 0; console.log(a.length);` Если же мы этого не хотим, то да, это наше право, но называть такое недонаследование наследованием как в ES6 неверно. Именно ради таких фич поменялась внутренняя схема наследования при использовании ES6-классов.

Comment: @Qwertiy ой слушайте, вы правы, не думал что оно так делает. Так как же нам наследовать от массива и перекрыть конструктор? Как же заполифилить такое наследование?

Comment: Ну так мы можем чего-то добавлять. Вот представь - взять и унаследовать jQuery-набор от массива. Кстати, есть ещё фишка: ты пишешь про переопределение методов, чтобы они возвращали нужный класс. А они в ES6 это и сами должны уметь - для этого есть специальное свойство: [`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species). `class A extends Array { }; var a = new A(1, 2, 3); console.log(a.map(x => x*x) instanceof A)` - тут true, а если сделать `class A extends Array { static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array } };`, то станет false.

Comment: Хм, спасибо за инфу. А ни кто еще не додумался символами приватные члены классов реализовывать?

Comment: Там уже настощие приватные поля в черновике появились. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/ `class C {
  #x;
  constructor(x){
    this.#x = x;
  }
  x(){
    return this.#x;
  }
}
return new C(42).x() === 42;`

Comment: Я знаю, я там (на их гитхабе) отписывался и идеями, и синтаксис и семантику гораздо круче придумал. Я имею ввиду, реализаций еще нет же?) Хотя бы тестовых

Comment: Нет, слишком рано ещё.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня вообще была идея что #слово  это такой типа уникальный символ генерируется, который имеет область видимости одного файла. Таким образом мы поулчаем гораздо более гибкий инструмент чем просто приватные свойства. Допустим мы можем на htmlElement поставить какую нить свою метку, понятную и доступную только нашему этому js файлу. div.#ololo = 11. Грубо говоря таким образом приватные ключи мы можем применять ко всем обьектам как нашей душе угодно, в том числе и к this.#prop у классов. Но они сказали что я гей и послали меня пить водку с матрешками.....

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52726/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-maxmaxmaximus).

Answer (score 0):

А давайте попробуем без Babel'я. Что нам на самом деле нужно?

Из того, что не обязано быть в ES5 - только [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Получаем IE11+ и все остальные браузеры. Причём IE10- принципиально в пролёте - мы не сможем воспроизвести поведение массива на обычном объекте и мы должны не портить сам массив.

```js
function Range() {
  var res = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  res.__proto__ = this.__proto__;

  res.smth = true;

  return res;
}

Range.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

Range.prototype.say = function () {
  console.log("I'm a range: " + this.smth + ", length: " + this.length);
};

// А теперь проверяем:

var a = new Range();
a.say();
a.push(12);
a.say();
a[3] = 0;
a.say();
console.log(a);
a.say();

var b = new Range(3);
console.log(b);
b.say();

var c = new Range(3, 5);
console.log(c);
c.say();

console.log(typeof [].say);
```

```css
html .as-console-wrapper { max-height: none; top: 0; }
```